# Set Text Area value in Twig Template

Tags: twig, symfony-2.8

I need to set values for form to edit. I need to set text in textarea. I tried following in my html.twig file,

```
<div class="form-group">
      {{ form_widget(blog_form.post_subheading1, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Subheading 1', 'value': post_data.postSubheading1 } }) }}
      {{ form_errors(blog_form.post_subheading1) }}
    </div>
```

In above situation value is added as attribute but not showing in the textarea ( I csn see it only inspecting element).

```
 <div class="form-group">
          {{ form_widget(blog_form.post_subheading1, {'value': post_data.postSubheading1 }, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Subheading 1'} }) }}
          {{ form_errors(blog_form.post_subheading1) }}
        </div>
```

In above situation can see text, but class and other attributes are missing. I need both class and text. How to archive this? I don't have this issue for text type. Only for textarea.

Here is my Type file,

```
 ->add('post_intro', 'textarea', array(
                'attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '6'),
                'required' => false
                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is in your Type file add `data` like so:

```
->add('post_intro', 'textarea', 
      'attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '6'),
      'required' => false
      'data' => "your text here"
      ))
```

If the value is dynamic set it with an option instead:

```
->add('post_intro', 'textarea', array(
      'attr' => array('cols' => '5', 'rows' => '6'),
      'required' => false
      'data' => $options["yourData"],
      ))
```

You can then send the data from your controller when you create your form. Controller:

```
$yourData = "something" // here you will set what you want to display in the field. 

$form = $this->createForm(YourClass::class, $yourClass, 
        ['yourData' => $yourData]);
```